# Getting N rows from far related table with conditions on close related table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables, `schedules` and `shifts`, with the relationship of one-to-many.

A `schedule` has `day`, `month`, `year` fields, as well as a `is_published` boolean. A `shift` has a `user_id` to have a relationship of one-to-one with `users`.

Now, I want to get the next 5 upcoming `shifts` of a `user`. I would have to start from `schedule` since that table has the date in it. But, more importantly, I should only retrieve the `shifts` that belong to a published `schedule`.

So the big problem is:

The number of entries should be the 5 shifts. However, starting from schedule, I would not know how many schedules I need to retrieve until there are 5 shifts belonging to a user.

Other than trial and error (i.e. retrieving x next schedules and testing to see if enough shifts exists. If not, retrieve the next n schedules until the quota is satisfied), is there an alternative?

**Schema of Schedule**

```
Schema::create('schedules', function(Blueprint $table) 
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id', false, true);
    $table->integer('client_id', false, true);
    $table->datetime('for');
    $table->enum('type', array('template', 'revision', 'common'));
    $table->string('name', 50)->default('Untitled Template');
    $table->boolean('is_published');
    $table->timestamp('published_at');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here, the `user_id` is the creator's id, NOT who the schedule belongs to. This is used to keep track on how created a schedule in the future.

**Schema of Shift**

```
Schema::create('shifts', function(Blueprint $table) 
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('schedule_id', false, true);
    $table->integer('user_id', false, true);
    $table->foreign('schedule_id')->references('id')->on('schedules')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Have you set up the relationships in your Eloquent models?

Comment: Yes, the relationships are set in the Eloquent table. My question is not how to link relationships, but how to get a certain number of a `shifts`, but starting from `schedule`

Comment: I got that, was just making sure... However I still have one question. you wrote that `shifts` has a one-to-one relationship with `users`. And on the other hand you say you want the upcoming 5 shifts that belong to the user. Do you actually want schedules in your result at the end?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, thanks for the reply. No, I don't want schedule at the end. I want to get an array of `shifts`. I want the user to be able to see their upcoming 5 shifts; these shifts could happen to be all from next week, or the 5 could span the next month or year. The reason I start from `schedule` is because `schedule` has the date entries in it. `shift` just references the `schedule` via the id of it.

Comment: 1 why you use such a strange schema for dates instead of a timestamp? 2 what result you expect exactly?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, you are absolutely correct. That was a mistake I had made, and I've fixed it now. But the core problem remains here, and that is not related to the date/timestamp.

Comment: @Kousha But you didn't answer - show me the result you expect, so I will tell you how to achieve that.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, I fixed the code. NOw there is only a datetime column called `for`. I would want a code that returns the x number of shifts of a user, starting from a given date (so the next 5 shifts that I work at from today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go the easy way:

```
// User model
public function shifts()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Shift', 'Schedule');
}
```

then:

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();

$upcomingShifts = $user->shifts()
     ->where('schedules.is_published', 1)
     ->where('schedules.for', '>', $now)
     ->orderBy('schedules.for')
     ->take(5)
     ->get();
```

You can make it a bit more flexible, eg. this way:

```
// User model
public function getUpcomingShifts($limit = 5)
{
   $joinTable = $this->shifts()->getParent()->getTable(); // schedules

   $now = Carbon\Carbon::now();

   return $this->shifts()
     ->where($joinTable.'.is_published', 1)
     ->where($joinTable.'.for', '>', $now)
     ->orderBy($joinTable.'.for')
     ->take($limit)
     ->get();
}

// then
$user->getUpcomingShifts();
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user.name, inner_q.* FROM user,
(SELECT sch.year, sch.month, sch.day, sh.start_time FROM schedule sch INNER JOIN shift sh ON sch.id=sh.schedule_id WHERE sch.is_published=TRUE AND sh.user_id=user.id LIMIT 5) AS inner_q;

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know if I got it all right, but give this a try:

```
User::find($userId)
    ->shifts()
    ->with('schedule')
    ->where('is_published', true)
    ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('day', 'asc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

**Update**

Second try, hope this works

```
User::find($userId)
    ->schedules()
    ->has('shifts')
    ->where('is_published', true)
    ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('day', 'asc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

**Another Update**

Third time is a charm :)

```
$results = User::find($userId)
    ->schedules()
    ->where('is_published', true)
    ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('day', 'asc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

For this to work you need this in your User model:

```
public function schedules(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Schedule', 'shifts');
}
```

So then to access the shift you can use the pivot property:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result->pivot
}
```

If you want the full Shift model instead of just the properties, define it as Pivot Model:

```
class Shift extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot
```

and in the Schedule model:

```
public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists){
    if ($parent instanceof User) {
        return new Shift($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but as I said, the `day`, `month`, `year`, and `is_published` is part the the `schedules` table, not the `shifts` table. That's exactly my problem; I want to `take(5)` but, that operation is invoked on `schedule`, NOT `shift`.

Comment: @Kousha okay, would it be possible for you to post the sql script for your db and your models? I'd like to try some things out

Comment: Sure, you want my Schema?

Comment: your schema or even a full dump ;)

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The `user_id` in the table `schedules` reflects  the creator of the schedule, as in you initiated the schedule. This is a schedule of an employeer for a given day. For each day, there are multiple shifts, or users, who work.

Comment: That would have too easy wouldn't it? ;)
Ok I have another one for you. It worked fine on the setup I created, however I didn't test all cases...
Answer is updated.

Comment: Haha that is true. It never is too easy! Now regarding your solution,  how does that help? You are taking 5 schedules; the user of interest may work everyday for thoese 5 schedules, and may NOT work for any of those days. So there is no guarantee how many shifts for that user the 5 schedules provide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63889/discussion-between-lukasgeiter-and-kousha).

Comment: @Kousha since you're not responding in the chat, here's my message:
Are you sure? Have you tried it out? Because in my tests it worked. Because we're joining over the shifts table we get a schedule in our collection for every shift in the shifts table... kinda hard to explain